# codeigniter file upload with other elements

Tags: image, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I've got a page with a form. On the form is a dropdownlist and a few inputboxes and a file upload. If I try to submit my page I get a blank page with the error 'Non-existent class: Upload'. I hadn't use file upload yet.

This is my input file type:

```
<tr><td>Image: </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="file" name="image" size="20" /></td></tr>
```

I've read on the CI file uploading class that you need a form_open_multipart('upload'); So will I just have that form or will I have to do something in else in my case? Because I got other input types on that form?

Here is a little bit code of my controller:

```
$subject = htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('subject')));
$message = htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('message')));
$image = $this->input->post('image');

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload($image)) {          
    $data['fout'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    $this->annuleren($soort, $data);
} else {
    $data['upload'] =  $this->upload->data();
}

$id = $this->message_model->insert($message, $subject, $image);

redirect('infoscreen/dashboard', 'refresh');
```

I've also made a folder 'uploads' under 'source files'. I'm probably doing something stupid. Can someone please help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I could fix it?

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: First load the upload library:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
```

Another problem lies in the fact that you're referencing the file wrong.

This row is unneccesary:

```
$image = $this->input->post('image'); // <- remove this line
```

Instead just use:

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
```

CodeIgniter by default is looking for a file input named 'userfile' but if that's not present you need to add `'image'` to the `do_upload()` method like this.

Then you have the line:

```
$id = $this->message_model->insert($message, $subject, $image);
```

I'm not certain what you think should be in the `$image` variable but if the upload succeded you can attach data from `$data['upload']`:

```
$id = $this->message_model->insert($message, $subject, $data['upload'][file_name]); // <- gets the filename
```

Full reference here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Also to answer your second question it is not a problem that the multipart form type has other input fields/types.

Comment: Oh ok, but I still got that error. What you mean with add the userfile to the do_upload?

Comment: Ahh, yes you will need to `$this->load->library('upload');` see my edit.

Comment: Even if I comment out the ->do_upload codes etc, it still gives the same error.

Comment: OK. Check that you have error reporting on (in your config file) and then see the log in application/logs/

Comment: Do you by any chance NOT have the file Upload.php in the folder system/libraries ???

Comment: I do have the file in system/libraries, but I've found out I also have one in my own libraries. I don't get any errors now. The name gets in the database but I can't find the image.

Comment: Let me guess that now there is only a problem left with the upload path. Where is the folder `./uploads/` and what rights are set? Try to change it into an absolute path for your server and make sure its chmod 777. (Also you shouldnt normally have a Upload library in application/libraries, remove that. Where did it came from? Its not CI default)

Comment: The upload file in system/libabry is default there I think, I didn't add it. I've got a folder 'uploads' under 'Source files', is that ok? But how can I change the permissions? It's a school server.

Comment: Just start with being 100% sure that your upload path set in `$config['upload_path']` is correct. I usually define the upload path in the constructor of my model using BASEPATH but you can do whatever. Also in these cases either the server error log (apache?) and/or the CI log can be useful for seeing what went wrong during upload. But I guess your setup is correct now other than the actual file transfer.

Comment: Got it all working now, my uploads folder was at the right position. NetBeans didn't show the images in the folder. I can only see them when I go into the folder via the url but that's okay. So thanks a lot for your help.